# saving udp data into an array

Tags: java, android, arrays, udp

I have a byte of array which receive UDP packets and I convert it to float array , the problem is that in every iteration it clear the array and write the packets that received there while I want to add new packets to array !

I use this code :

```
float[] receive = new float[] {}
```

how should I change this to add receiving packets to my array ?

Comment: We need to see some more code to know what exactly is the cause that your array gets cleared up in every iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume every time a UDP packet is received, you are putting the data into that array which explains why it gets erased at every iteration.
Use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to save the received bytes

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
while (receiving) {
    out.write(received_data, 0, received_data_size);
}
```

Once done, you can get all received bytes by doing:

```
byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
```

And then do the `float` conversion

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are a fixed size data structure. You should be using `java.util.ArrayList` instead. If the boxing overhead is not acceptable, you can write your own custom `ArrayList` specialized for integers, or use one of the [similar available solutions](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 0):

I will guess that the line you posted:

float[] receive = new float[] {}

is inside the loop.
So every loop the `receive` variable will get a new empty `float` array.

You should put the declaration of `receive` outside the loop.
And missingfaktor is right, you better use `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList<Float> receive;
...
receive.add(<your data>);
...
```